# Windows 7 Ultimate loaded over Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows

Can I load Windows 7 Ultimate over Windows 8?  The laptop I wish to buy uses Windows 8.  I prefer Windows 7.  Can I load Windows 7 over Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to buy a separate Windows 7 retail license (Windows 8 does not include downgrade rights), but there is no reason you can't format the harddrive and install Windows 7 upon it.